# WPF Grouping HeaderTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

Let's say I have done some grouping in a listbox in WPF

```
<ListBox Name="bob" xmlns:swd="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Data;assembly=PresentationFramework">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="view">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <swd:PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Group"></swd:PropertyGroupDescription>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </ListBox.Resources>

    <ListBox.ItemsSource>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource view}"></Binding>
    </ListBox.ItemsSource>

    <ListBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Background="Red" TextElement.Foreground="White">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Name}">
                            <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock><Run Text="("></Run><Run Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"></Run><Run Text=")"></Run></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListBox.GroupStyle>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Item}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

and have populated the view in code like so:

```
var view = bob.FindResource("view") as CollectionViewSource;
view.Source = "Mary,Mark,Jane,Joey,Justin"
    .Split(',')
    .GroupBy(i => i[0])
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select(i => new { Group = g.Key, Item = i }))
    .ToArray();
```

This is all working really well except that the look of the group header, the Border with the red background, needs to be defined for every listbox that I do grouping on. If I then want green I need to change it everywhere. I could take the colour out and make that a resource or put it in a style, but what if I want to add an icon, or some other item.

What I really want to be able to do is take out the HeaderTemplate and define it somewhere once. But then the ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate inside that be able to specify a different one for each list. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on what you want to achieve but it sounds like what you are looking for is a DataTemplateSelector?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx